# MVC - writing to the Head section from View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to render a meta tag in the  section of my page from the view. For example, the view contains all the product information, I want to add the product information to the head but only have access to this from the product page.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into defining and using sections - they allow you to write to other areas from a view.

Or define the meta tag items in ViewBag, write out ViewBag.Meta in the head as the meta tag and populate that ViewBag property in the controller - the order works fine.

Answer (score 12):

In your Layout, define a Section in the head. We can use the [`RenderSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg537886%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) helper method to do so.

Use the `RenderSection` method when you want to render optional content sections in a layout page. So we will update our Layout like this

```
<head>
  <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript" />
  @RenderSection("MetaContent", false)
</head>
<body>
 @RenderBody()
</body>
```

Now in your pages/views, you can pass the content of this section. I would add a new property to my viewmodel/base viewmodel to hold the meta description. So in your GET Action method, you set the `MetaDescription` property value.

And in your view, which is strongly typed to ProductViewModel

```
@model ProductViewModel
<h1>@Model.ProductName</h1>
<div>@Model.ProductDesc</div>
@section MetaContent
{
  <meta name="description" content="@Model.MetaDescription" />
}
```

When we defined section in the layout, we used `false` as second parameter value. That means this section is not required. you do not need to pass the meta information from all the views/pages.

Checkout Scottgu's [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) about sections and layouts.